# A purely numerical sequence with a hint of the visual

Tags: number-sequence

What is the missing number in this cyclic sequence?
It would require a notation convention not seen here
to fit into the scheme here.

$$\phantom{
\textrm{(repeat)} }
\quad\textbf{?}~~ \,,~~ 2.4  \,,~~ 1   \,,~~ 36.0
                  \,,~~ 1    \,,~~ 8   \,,~~ 1  \,,~~ 15 \,,~~ 2.4
                  \,,~~ 1    \,,~~ 8.0 \,,~~ \frac{~9~}2 ,
\phantom{         \,,~ \dots }
\\
\textrm{(repeat)}
\quad\textbf{?}~~ \,,~~ 2.4  \,,~~ 1   \,,~~ 36.0
                  \,,~ \dots
\phantom{         \,,~~ 1    \,,~~ 8   \,,~~ 1  \,,~~ 15 \,,~~ 2.4
                  \,,~~ 1    \,,~~ 8.0 \,,~~ \frac{~9~}2 , }
$$

Hintified from comments:

> $8$ vs $8.0\,$?   $2.4$ vs $\frac92$?  
>  All relevant properties, including the visual one, are mathematical.

[Half](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/half-truth#Noun)$/$ [hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tell_%28poker%29):

> The visible clue:
>  $2.4$, $36.0$, $2.4$ and $8.0$ are not represented as reduced fractions.

Comment: Is it significant that one number is $8$ while another is $8.0$?

Comment: I think 'visual' is a hint, but I can't figure out how it helps. I've been looking at ways to measure visual acuity, but can't see how any of the numbers fit.

Comment: Is the sequence cyclic?

Comment: The above comments have prompted a more-periodic layout and a "Hintified from comments" fortune cookie

Comment: Your hints are very... hinty. Any more?

Comment: @question_asker, I've added a half solution as another hintie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your old friend question_asker here. I've got the answer, and it's

> $3.\overline{3}$ or $3.333...$

Why, you ask?

> Who knows!

Well, then how did I get the answer?

> Brute force! Kind of!

*(record scratch)* lol what

> Yeah, look, I went to college for like 1.5 semesters before dropping out, and during the semester I liked, I took Calculus I, and while I enjoyed it, it was the last of my formal math education.
>
>  Anyway, the kind (non-, as per their profile) doctor had *at one point* left a hint on this question: *"This sequence rolled out in reverse order as reciprocals for a probability problem [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability?sort=newest)."* In a brief chat with Pangloss, they mentioned that the sequence was only of importance with regard to *games* where *randomness* was necessary (emphasis mine). From this I could narrow down that the problem I was looking for probably involved dice or a coin flip. Skimming those problems, I found that, lo and behold, there was [a problem that involved both](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16333/how-to-get-a-uniform-1-out-of-7-chance-using-only-a-coin-and-a-6-sided-die), and specifically [an answer that had the exact thing mentioned in the hint](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16333/how-to-get-a-uniform-1-out-of-7-chance-using-only-a-coin-and-a-6-sided-die/26061#26061). I "checked" the "math" briefly and realized that it was, in fact, the reciprocals of the elements of the sequence in reverse. From this I could conclude that the missing value was $10/3$, and since it was mentioned that *the missing element required a notation convention not already seen in the puzzle*, I realized it must be $3.\overline{3}$ or $3.333...$
>
>  As such, with Pangloss's blessing, I am posting this answer and awaiting my parade.

Comment: Cheers to a solution that marshals so many resources! The purely mathematical approach had its chance for half a month before you revived this puzzle.

Comment: @Pangloss I may not be educated, but I'm resourceful, dammit

Comment: The [old chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35861/cyclic-puzzle-collabo) is open again if you'd like to add to this solution

Answer (score 1):

Possibly halfway to a solution, here's my worksheet so far.

> \begin{matrix}                                                               & 9&~~?~~& 12  & 1 &  36 & 1 & 8 & 1 &  15  & 12  & 1 &  8  & 9 &~~?~~& 12  &          \\[-1ex] \cdots                                                          & -&     &\cdot& - &\cdot& - & - & - &-\!\!-&\cdot& - &\cdot& - &     &\cdot&   \cdots \\[-1ex]                                                                 & 2&  ?  &  5  & 1 &  1  & 1 & 1 & 1 &   1  &  5  & 1 &  1  & 2 &  ?  &  5  &   \end{matrix}
>  Think I could almost stagger the rest of the way,

without fully figuring out the rule.
Then again, what was that about notation convention?

Comment: Pangloss, I hate you.

Comment: For the record, that's my upvote you're seeing on this answer, as well as that on your comment.

Comment: When you refer to a "notation convention", are you referring to this thing above with the dots and dashes, or something entirely separate?

Comment: I thought that might be the case, I just wanted to get every possibility I had considered onto the page, so to speak, in case it jumpstarted anybody else's thought processes.